# Finding maxDate for each entity

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server

I have a table with `(CompanyNumber, File_Date, [various financial results])`
I wanted to get only the most recent set of accounts for each company.

After various googling I eventually got a query that does what I want it to do.

Is this a good way of doing it?

**N.B.** the `File_Date` field is actually a `text` field, so needs converting to `Date` before comparisons. Specifically, `text --> varchar --> date`.

```
select * from uk_registered_companies.dbo.Filed_Accounts 
JOIN
(
Select companyNumber, max(convert(date, CONVERT(varchar(20),file_date),103)) as MaxDate from uk_registered_companies.dbo.Filed_Accounts
group by CompanyNumber
) mostRecentAccounts
on
Filed_Accounts.CompanyNumber = mostRecentAccounts.CompanyNumber
and
(convert(date, CONVERT(varchar(20),Filed_Accounts.File_Date),103)) = mostRecentAccounts.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick review, there are a few things I think you could improve, they are mostly a matter of style though.

---

#### Casing

Just pick a casing style and stick to it, you are actually using all 3 casing styles kind of randomly.

---

#### Common Table Expression (or, CTE)

In Transact-SQL/ Microsoft SQL Server, there's a syntax sugar type of expression to help reduce sub-queries, the execution plan from the query engine should be the same but they help readability.

For instance, look at this join clause:

> ```
> from 
>   uk_registered_companies.dbo.Filed_Accounts 
> JOIN (
>   Select 
>       companyNumber, 
>       max(convert(date, CONVERT(varchar(20),file_date),103)) as MaxDate 
>   from 
>       uk_registered_companies.dbo.Filed_Accounts
>     group by CompanyNumber
> ) as mostRecentAccounts
> ```

You could do something like this:

```
--Here is the CTE:
with mostRecentAccounts as (
        select 
            companyNumber, 
            max(convert(date, CONVERT(varchar(20),file_date),103)) as MaxDate 
        from 
            uk_registered_companies.dbo.Filed_Accounts
        group by CompanyNumber
)
--end of CTE
select 
    * 
from 
    uk_registered_companies.dbo.Filed_Accounts
join
    mostRecentAccounts 
  on 
    Filed_Accounts.CompanyNumber = mostRecentAccounts.CompanyNumber
  and
    (convert(date, CONVERT(varchar(20),Filed_Accounts.File_Date),103)) = mostRecentAccounts.MaxDate
```

---

#### Indentation

I did a few changes to your formatting to make it easier to read. For indenting, I usually have the following keywords to the left, and indent everything else accordingly, kind of a crapshoot as there is no official style guide:

```
with Foo as (
    --...
)
select
  --...
from
  --...
join
  --...
    on --...
where
  --...
group by
  --...
having
 --...
order by
 --...
```

Comment: Could you expound a bit on your indenting style? It looks nice and I want to emulate it.

Comment: @Zak made an edit

Answer (score 1):

The common way to get the max/min per group utilizes Standard SQL's RANK, it usually simplifies the query (especially if you got Joins/Where-conditions which must be repeated in both Selects). Depending on the actual data/indexes/DBMS it might be more efficient, too:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 (
   SELECT acc.*,
      RANK() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY companyNumber
            ORDER BY convert(date, CONVERT(varchar(20),file_date),103) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM uk_registered_companies.dbo.Filed_Accounts AS acc
 ) AS dt
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Or using a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT acc.*,
      RANK() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY companyNumber
            ORDER BY convert(date, CONVERT(varchar(20),file_date),103) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM uk_registered_companies.dbo.Filed_Accounts AS acc
 ) 
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
```

There's only one downside, you probably don't want to return the `rnk` column (in this query it's always the same value, `1`), so you have to list all columns:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ..., columnx
FROM cte/dt
```

But using `*`is not recommended anyway :)

Phrancis already commented on casing/indenting...